# Ambiguously named executables

Tags: path, executable, tcsh, version

It appears that in `tcsh` if I have ambiguously named executables in two separate folders in the `$PATH` it directs to the one in the most recently created folder.  Am I correct?  And is this always true?

Comment: Can you give an example?

Answer (score 1):

In general it will be the order it is found in `$PATH` since that is the intended usage for `$PATH`.

There could be an exception to this rule but that would require that the command is hard coded with a directory to the command in the software. I would consider that bad practice though.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have two files with the same name in the same directory. If there are several versions of `prog`, you have one e.g. in `/usr/bin` and another one in `/usr/local/bin`, and the `PATH` environment variable decides which one is picked. This is done by one of the `exec(3)` family which looks at the `PATH` (most probably `execvp(3)`), the shell has no saying here.

Comment: I meant if both are in the same path... e.g. if you have a folder called NAMD27 and NAMD27b3 in the path and each has an executable `namd2`.  How does `exec(3)` pick which one has priority?? (It appears to be the newest one, but the second one comes later in the path, so it could be the order in the path as well...)

Answer (score 0):

In Solaris, there are typically two directories (actually more than two) that contain different versions of the same name program.  An example is `ps` which is found in `/usr/ucb` and `/usr/bin`.  If both `/usr/ucb` and `/usr/bin` appear in your `PATH`, the version of `ps` that gets executed is whichever one appears first in your `PATH`.

Answer (score 0):

All shells traverse the directories in the `$PATH` in order, and execute the first command they find. For example, if your path is `/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin`, then the command from `/usr/local/bin` is executed if there is one; if there isn't, the command from `/usr/bin` is executed, and so on. It doesn't matter in which order the commands were installed.

There's one exception: if you install a program while the shell is already running, the shell may have kept the location of the program in a cache, in which case it will keep executing the old program. For example, if you start tcsh, then you run `foo` which is at that point `/usr/bin/foo`, then you install another version of the program in `/usr/local/bin/foo` and call `foo` from that shell again, it will still run `/usr/bin/foo`. A newly started shell will pick up `/usr/local/bin/foo`. Run the command `rehash` to empty tcsh's cache of command locations. In bash and zsh, the equivalent command is `hash -r` (zsh also understands `rehash`).